# Upgrade php version from 5.2 to 5.3 Joomla

Tags: php-5.3

Our new website in Joomla 3 needs at least PHP v5.3 to run the Akeeba Next Generation Installer. Any my server is running a PHP 5.2. I have tried adding the line

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php

on my .htaccess but instead it downloads the index.php file.. Hosting provided is Doteasy. How do we go upgrading the PHP?

Any help would be much appreciated. THanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work. You'll need to have php installed to the version. Do you have SSH access to the server? if you do what platform is it? Most web servers run on Linux and if that's the case you'll need to upgrade php on the linux server. On Windows you'll need to 
uninstall and install php to the latest.

a, 
 if it is centos or fedora, you need to have the correct repo enabled and you need to issue

To install, first you must add the Webtatic EL yum repository information corresponding to your CentOS/RHEL version to yum:

CentOS/RHEL 7.x:

```
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/epel-release.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
CentOS/RHEL 6.x:

rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
CentOS/RHEL 5.x:

rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el5/latest.rpm
Now you can install php by doing:

yum install php54w
If you would like to upgrade php to this version it is recommended that you check that your system will support the upgrade, e.g. making sure any CPanel-like software can run after the upgrade.

Unless you know what you are doing, it is risky upgrading an existing system. It’s much safer to do this by provisioning a separate server to perform the upgrade as a fresh install instead.

If you know what you are doing, you can upgrade PHP by:

yum install yum-plugin-replace

yum replace php-common --replace-with=php54w-common
It will likely give you a message “WARNING: Unable to resolve all providers …”. This is normal, and you can continue by tying “y“. You will be given a chance to see what packages will be installed and removed before again being given a chance to confirm.
```

or

if its a debian ubuntu linux dist you need to issue

```
*this will be the easiest option. For PHP 5.4.x run the command:*

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
or for PHP 5.5.x run:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
And then update your packages:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: That's the problem.. I do not have access to the SSH.. I have tried contacting Doteasy support.. No response yet.